# Once I get a value from a dropdown menu can I compare it with a string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

All I've is this but i get no value from the dropdown menu for java script to compare it to a string

```
    // JavaScript Document
var singleMulticontainer = document.getElementById("singleMultiContainer");
var singleMultiValue =  singleMultiContainer.options[singleMultiContainer.selectedIndex].value;
var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextButton");
var multipleSetWindow = "window.location='multiSet.html'"

if(singleMultiValue == "multi"){
    document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("data-location", "multiSet.html");
}
else{
    alert("notworking");
}
```

And the dropdown menu is this one: how do i get the value from the options of single or multi container?

```
<form id"suspendedProperties">
    <p><h4>Select Station:
    <select name="stationDropdown">
        <option value="50028000">Tanama</option>
        <option value="60008001">Example Riv1</option>
        <option value="60008002">Example Riv2</option>
        <option value="60008003">Example Riv3</option>
        <option value="60008004">Example Riv4</option>
     </select>
     </h4></p>

    <p>Select Sample Medium:
        <select name="sampleMediumDropdown">
          <option value="Wer">Wer</option>
          <option value="WSQ">WSQ</option>
        </select>
        </p>
    <p>Begin Date
        <input type="date"/>
     </p>
     <p>Hydrologic Event: <select name="hydroEvent">
                            <option value="1">Example 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Example 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Example 3</option>
                            <option value="4">Example 4</option>
                            <option value="5">Example 5</option>
                            <option value="6">Example 6</option>
                          </select>
</p>
<p>Add:<input type="number" size=""/> <select name="singleMultiContainer"><option value="single">Single container sample</option><option value="multi">Multiple sets container</option></select></p>
 <p>Analyses Requested:(Applies to all samples)<br/></p>
 <div id="analyses" >
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="C">Concentration</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SF">Sand-fine break**</input>&nbsp;  
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SA">Sand analysis**</input>  <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="T">Turbidity</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="LOI">Loss-on-ignition**</input>&nbsp;    
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="DS">Dissolve solids</input>  <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SC">Specific conductance</input>                                     
 <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="Z">Full-size fractions**</input>
 </div>
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.location='SED_WE.html'"/>
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="window.location='SampleInfo.html'"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what values do you want to compare?

Comment: You need to give your select an id to be able to `getElementById('singleMultiContainer')`

Comment: Notice `<form id="suspendedProperties">` is missing an `=`

Comment: is this helping you? http://jsfiddle.net/FnByB/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I want to compare the value of a option in the singleMultiContainer with a string.

Comment: You are assigning the element to `singleMulticontainer` but are using the variable `singleMultiContainer` in the next step (capital C). It is not clear when the code runs. If it runs before the user selected a value, you will only get the default value. Overall it's not clear what exactly the problem is. You cannot just dump your code and expect us to fix everything that is wrong.

Comment: @Ch32k0 did it worked for you?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling I'm looking for a reference on how to get a value from a dropdown menu and compare it to a string, not for people to fix my code, some people just made me realize of my mistakes in the code.

Comment: Well then, how to get the value is already [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/218196) and for the comparison you are have to use one of the two [equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pGanF/)

You had forgot to ad a id to your select. I added `<select name="singleMultiContainer" id="singleMultiContainer">` which had no id although you were "looking for it" in your script.
You had also some typo errors, I fixed those I found, so please check if this is what you want.

HTLM

```
<form id="suspendedProperties">
    <p>
        <h4>Select Station:
    <select name="stationDropdown">
        <option value="50028000">Tanama</option>
        <option value="60008001">Example Riv1</option>
        <option value="60008002">Example Riv2</option>
        <option value="60008003">Example Riv3</option>
        <option value="60008004">Example Riv4</option>
     </select>
     </h4>
    </p>
    <p>Select Sample Medium:
        <select name="sampleMediumDropdown">
            <option value="Wer">Wer</option>
            <option value="WSQ">WSQ</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Begin Date
        <input type="date" />
    </p>
    <p>Hydrologic Event:
        <select name="hydroEvent">
            <option value="1">Example 1</option>
            <option value="2">Example 2</option>
            <option value="3">Example 3</option>
            <option value="4">Example 4</option>
            <option value="5">Example 5</option>
            <option value="6">Example 6</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Add:
        <input type="number" size="" />
        <select name="singleMultiContainer" id="singleMultiContainer">
            <option value="single">Single container sample</option>
            <option value="multi">Multiple sets container</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Analyses Requested:(Applies to all samples)
        <br/>
    </p>
    <div id="analyses">
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="C">Concentration</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SF">Sand-fine break**</input>&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SA">Sand analysis**</input>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="T">Turbidity</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="LOI">Loss-on-ignition**</input>&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="DS">Dissolve solids</input>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="SC">Specific conductance</input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value="Z">Full-size fractions**</input>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.location='SED_WE.html'" />
    <input type="button" value="Next" id="nextButton" onClick="window.location='SampleInfo.html'" />
</form>
```

JS

```
// JavaScript Document
var singleMultiContainer = document.getElementById("singleMultiContainer");
var singleMultiValue = singleMultiContainer.options[singleMultiContainer.selectedIndex].value;
var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextButton");
var multipleSetWindow = "window.location='multiSet.html'"

if (singleMultiValue == "multi") {
    document.getElementById("nextButton").setAttribute("onclick", "window.location='multiSet.html'");
} else {
    alert("notworking");
}
```

Comment: If typos are the only problem, the question should be closed instead.

Comment: @FelixKling, good point. Thank you. He had also forgot to add id to the select. WIll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Sergio I fixed my typos, i also made the id fix. Thank you, it's kind of working, but anyway I'll look deeper into my code, thank you anyways.

Comment: @Ch32k0, why 'kind of working' ? what are you missing?

Comment: @Ch32k0, check this http://jsfiddle.net/gKXWr/ - I added an event for your multi string compare. Useful?

Comment: @Sergio it goes directly to the alert, it's a logic mistake. Let me try to fix it but thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gKXWr/ - @Ch32k0, but check and change to multi, it will give the other alert.

Comment: @Sergio It gives me the other alert when i hit back.

Comment: @Ch32k0, and what is the behavior you want to happen?

Comment: @Sergio I want that as soon as you choose to have a multiple container the link to the next page changes to another link immediately

Comment: @Ch32k0, i see. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/pGanF/

Comment: @Sergio In JSFIDDLE runs perfectly, but as soon I make changes in DW and test it it does the same :s